# GetLegendGraphic return a symbol instead of colormap ramp

Tags: getlegendgraphic

I'm trying to put inside an OpenLayers project the legend for an NDVI map. Previously I've created with QGIS 3.10 the SLD as indicated on the [GeoServer's official documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/qgis/index.html#exporting-raster-symbology).

When I try to use [GetLegendGraphic](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#colormap-type-is-ramp) to see the legend's preview I see only the symbol of raster and not the legend. If I set the style as default for my raster layer I can use the link from GetLegendGraphic for see correcty my legend. But If I set "*Associated*" instead of "*Dafault*" I see again the raster's symbol.

Why I'm obligated to use "Default" for styling a raster?

***EDIT***

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506123612/https://gis.massimilianomoraca.it/geoserver/MassimilianoMoraca/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=MassimilianoMoraca:NDVI_Campania_20150807&bbox=399960.0,4490220.0,509760.0,4600020.0&width=768&height=768&srs=EPSG:32633&format=application/openlayers) the WMS stylized(**A**) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507002012/https://gis.massimilianomoraca.it/geoserver/MassimilianoMoraca/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=MassimilianoMoraca:NDVI_Campania_20160712&bbox=399960.0,4490220.0,509760.0,4600020.0&width=768&height=768&srs=EPSG:32633&format=application/openlayers) the WMS not stylized(**B**). The style name is NDVI.

`https://gis.massimilianomoraca.it/geoserver/MassimilianoMoraca/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&LAYER=NDVI_Campania_20150807&SCALE=136494.42037699942`

gives

[image: For A]

it is possible to see the legend and is not possible to do the same with

`https://gis.massimilianomoraca.it/geoserver/MassimilianoMoraca/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&LAYER=NDVI_Campania_20160712&SCALE=136494.42037699942`

[image: for B].

The layer A has NDVI as default style and for B I've used "*Associated*".

Comment: can you add the actual URLs you are requesting and the results in each case

Comment: I've do this now @IanTurton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the style you would like the the legend to use if you don't want to use the default one - in the same way as you must to make it appear in the map.

So `https://gis.massimilianomoraca.it/geoserver/MassimilianoMoraca/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&LAYER=NDVI_Campania_20160712&SCALE=136494.42037699942&style=NDVI` will return:

[image]